# Making multiple curl requests without timeout.

Tags: php, curl

I am developing a system where I need to fetch 5000+ users location using multiple GET request. Unfortunately the API endpoint doesn't support multiple client ids. ie. I have to make 5000+ unique get requests to fetch their locations and use (the cumulative response) to make another API call.

I am using CURL to make the requests. I used the following snippet[[1]](http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/) to make the request.

```
<?php

function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}

?>
```

It works perfectly for small number of requests but when I try to hit 1000+ it gets timeout.

```
    $data = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        $data[] = 'https://foo.bar/api/loc/v/queries/location?address=XXXXXXXXX';

    }
    $token = $this->refresh();

    $r = $this->multiRequest($data, $token);
```

What is the best approach to solve this issue?

- a. Increase the maximum_execution_time of the PHP script or
- b. Use something like multi threading or
- c. Other

Comment: It's not perfect when you using threading in PHP, it susceptible to bottlenecks of requests, it can make the system unstable. I think good solution is a queue (ex: RabbitMQ) + java process (or nodejs) to support php make multiple requests. You can limit requests for this process, multiple threading, control the memory. It is important to separate tasks with PHP for web remains smooth operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to modify endpoint API to allow to process multiple ids? If yes, that is preferred, because if you run several thousands of requests at the same time, you actually making something like DDoS attack.

However, you may want to check PHP's curl_multi_* functions (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php).

Another link that can be useful: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

Comment: Cannot modify the API endpoint ( not in my control). I am actually using curl_multi_* functions in the code.

Comment: Is there a way to catch the user location change event and update dynamically when location changed?

Comment: well, no. If i want to do that I want to again poll.

Comment: OK. Is location something that changes frequently? Maybe you can process the task by portions (e.g. during a day)?

Comment: Yep. Location does change frequently. but the requirement for pulling the locations is usually urgent.